# How can I draw shapes other than cubes?

Tags: shapes, x3dom

How can I draw shapes other than cubes with x3dom? For instance, one shape I want to draw is a semi circle/cylinder. I can only find documentation to draw a cube which I already do. I have not found good documentation yet for x3dom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X3DOM actually just wraps X3D. So you may better start with the X3D [documentation](http://www.web3d.org/files/specifications/19775-1/V3.2/Part01/components/geometry3D.html). A quite good overview can be found here: [X3D Slides](http://x3dgraphics.com/slidesets/index.php).

There are some other primitives provided like:

```
<Shape>
  <Sphere radius='1'/>
  <Appearance>
    <Material/>
  </Appearance>
</Shape>
```

Also the [examples](http://www.x3dom.org/?page_id=5) provide a good [starting point](http://x3dom.org/x3dom/example/x3dom_geoPrimitives.xhtml).

Comment: So, I used the cylinder tag and I'm assuming I cannot do a semi radius on it. I don't see any options for that based on the documentation provided. I tried to use the Geometry2D with ArcClose2D, but that only creates a flat object on the x and y coordinates. I cannot rotate it down or extrude it. I wanted to try and stay away from using the Index faces tag because this will be variable data.

Comment: As @drfrog pointed out you might want to use Blender or other software to make your models. If it is variable data and it is computed automatically then you might want to use the chance of ArcClose2D with some IndexedFaceSets to make a half-cylinder on your own.

Answer (score 0):

to use a cylinder just use this in the shape node

```
<Cylinder />
```

as mistapink says check out the x3d docs, there are a few basic x3d primitives, such as sphere box cylinder cone.

anything more elaborate would require you to use pointsets etc. or you can model your own objects and export to x3d through lots of 3d apps, blender , 3d max , lightwave etc